# SetWindowLongPtr with DialogBoxParam?

Tags: c++, winapi

A while back I was writing a C++ program with the Win32 API that would display a dialog box and then listen to the messages it generated.  At one point, I was interested in associating a piece of data with the dialog window.  Were I manually creating the window and attaching a window proc, I'd just use `SetWindowLongPtr` to set the `GWLP_USERDATA` field to a pointer to the data to associate.  However, in this case I was creating and displaying the window with `DialogBoxParam`, and it wasn't clear whether this function was associating that data with its own internal state.  Since the MSDN didn't have a description of what would happen in this case, I ended up using some other approach to solve the problem.

My question is this - is it safe to use `SetWindowLongPtr` to overwrite the `GWLP_USERDATA` value in a window created by `DialogBoxParam`?

Comment: If you are not in charge of registering the window class, then I don't believe you can claim ownership of the data at GWLP_USERDATA, but I'm not 100% sure about this. Why can't you use the dwInitParam
of DialogBoxParam? Alternatively you could use GetProp/SetProp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the GWLP_USERDATA is for the use of the (base in the case of subclassing) window class to use. Because dialogs are a ready made class, GWLP_USERDATA is for internal use - whihc is why dialogs supply a DWLP_USER field for your DialogProc implementation's use.

As things stand however, all the internal window classes supplied by Microsoft - EDIT, BUTTON, Dialog and so on, do not, and cannot use GWLP_USERDATA for application compatibility reasons, so they are effectively available for the application to use.